# How do you fix 'EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink {FILE PATH}' errors?

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

Whenever I run `npm run build` on my project now, for whatever reason I get an error saying:

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink '{File path here}'] {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'unlink',
  path: '{File path here}'
}
```

I have tried:

- `npm i`
- `npm install --no-optional`
- `npm i -g npm@5.3`
- `npm cache clean`
- `npm cache clean --force`
- `npm unlink`

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Before `npm unlink`, you should execute `npm unlink --no-save your-packge` at first.